# Getting error when trying to load fragment shader from file

Tags: c++, file, opengl-es, shader

The issue is as such: Placing my shader code inside a std::string like so

```cpp
std::string vertex_shader_source = 
        "#version 300 es\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 verts;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "    gl_Position = verts;\n"
        "}\n";

std::string fragment_shader_source =
        "#version 300 es\n"
        "precision mediump float;"
        "out vec3 color;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "    color = vec3(1,0,0);\n"
        "}\n";
```

works completely fine, with the program reporting no errors, but as soon as I try to load the exact same data from a file the fragment shader seems to compile just fine, but the program reports there's an error when linking and validating. The error string that gets returned is either blank, or filled with garbage, so I can't gleam anything useful from that either.

I've heared people say it might've had to do with the line-ending characters used by Windows, but after rewriting the code on Linux it doesn't change at all.

I've included the entire program I'm trying to make work in a [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/BeWA5SqB), (the shader files I used are the exact same as the ones in the pastebin, except for the quotes and newlines)
All I can guess right now is that there is something wrong with the way I read the file in the Renderer::compile_shader_from_file() method on line 93, but whenever I try loading it in a seperate program and checking the string's contens it looks just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `Renderer::compile_shader_from_file`, 2 shader objects are created (`glCreateShader` is called twice). Finally the "wrong" object is returned from the method:

> ```cpp
> unsigned int Renderer::compile_shader_from_file(const std::string& file_path, GLenum shader_type) {
>    std::ifstream shader_source_file(file_path);
>    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
>
>    if(shader_source_file.is_open()) {
>        // [...]
>
>        unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
>
>        // [...]
>    }
>    shader_source_file.close();
>    return shader;
> }
> ```

Create just 1 object, to solve the issue:

```cpp
unsigned int Renderer::compile_shader_from_file(const std::string& file_path, GLenum shader_type) {
    std::ifstream shader_source_file(file_path);
    unsigned int shader = 0;                     // <---

    if(shader_source_file.is_open()) {
        // [...]

        shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);    // <---

        // [...]
    }
    shader_source_file.close();
    return shader;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue, after fixing that along with a few other dumb mistakes it works! Makes me wonder how I didn't catch that myself yet.